# How to properly POST json data to Web API 2 actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web app that uses HTTP POST to send data to a ASP.NET Web API 2 action. The Web API action is hit, but the data are all null.

The POST is sent from:

```
var url = 'http://MyWebApi/api/MyController/MyAction/1';
var obj = { pamA: 'a', pamB: 1 };
var data = { json: ko.toJSON(obj) };
// var data = ko.toJSON(obj); // tried this too, but same problem.

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    data: data,
});
```

My Web API action is:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
[System.Web.Http.Route("{id:int}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Models.MyModel))]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(int id, Models.MyModel json){
  return Ok(200); // break point is hit but json doesn't have the data sent from client.
}
```

and my model is:

```
public class MyModel{
    public string pamA {get; set;}
    public int pamB {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Try: `var data = ko.toJSON(obj);`

Comment: @ChrisPratt, I tried that, but still the same problem. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, then next up, use `contentType: "application/json"` in your AJAX call.

Comment: You might also want to try prefixing your `json` param with `[FromBody]`: `[FromBody]Models.MyModel json`

Comment: @ChrisPratt, changing 'dataType' to 'contentType' with value 'application/json' fixed it. How weird! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off I suggest for clarity that you mark where your parameters are coming from in your web action. Something like this

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
[System.Web.Http.Route("{id:int}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Models.MyModel))]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromUri]int id, [FromBody]Models.MyModel json){
  return Ok(200); // break point is hit but json doesn't have the data sent from client.
}
```

Now that is not your problem, just me being obsessive. Anyways I think your problem is stemming from your ajax request.

```
var url = 'http://MyWebApi/api/MyController/MyAction/1';
var obj = { pamA: 'a', pamB: 1 };
var data = { json: ko.toJSON(obj) };

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    data: data,
});
```

should be:

```
var url = 'http://MyWebApi/api/MyController/MyAction/1';
var data = { pamA: 'a', pamB: 1 };

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    data: data,
});
```

Your MyModel object is expecting the json to have fields pamA and pamB. But your json object *actually* looks like this {"json": {"pamA":"a", "pamB":1} }
Your json says that the object should contain a property called "json" that maps to an object with properties pamA and pamB. In order for your MyModel object to be able to map to the json your are currently sending it it would have to look like this.

```
public class OtherModel {
       public MyModel json;
}
```

But I suggest your just do away with the "json" field and make your json request look like this: { pamA: 'a', pamB: 1 }

Comment: changing var data = {pamA: 'a', pamB: 1} made it work. the location markers [FromUri] are optional.

Comment: Yes I know they are optional, I just said that was a suggestion. Its something that I like to do to make it clear where the data is coming from. 

So I answered the question and no upvote?

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery's `ajax` method, `dataType` specifies what you're expecting as a response, so you're probably still going to need that. The `contentType` option specifies how the request body is formatted and defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so you need to specify `application/json` instead.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: url,
    data: data,
});
```